# Toggle button not working

Tags: togglebutton, jquery

My toggle button was working fine, but i made some tweaks to another part of my code and now it has stopped working. the reset button in the same panel also works fine. this is what i am doing-

```
$(document.getElementById('light')).toggle(function () {
        $(document.getElementById('grid ')).css('backgroundColor ', '#000000');
        $(document.getElementByClassName('circle')).css('borderColor', '# FFFF99 ');
    }, function () {
        $(document.getElementById('grid ')).css('backgroundColor ', '#c0c0c0 ');
        $(document.getElementByClassName('circle ')).css('borderColor ', '#FAEBD7 ');
    });
```

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/riamirchi/yhb9A/84/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't get it right about what toogle-button stands for you I made some improvements to that part of your code:

```
$('#light').toggle(function () {
    $('#grid ').css('backgroundColor ', '#000000');
    $('.circle').css('borderColor', '# FFFF99 ');
}, function () {
    $('#grid ').css('backgroundColor ', '#C0C0C0 ');
    $('.circle ').css('borderColor ', '#FAEBD7 ');
});

$('#reset').click(function () {
    $('#grid').css('backgroundColor ', '#C0C0C0');
    $('.circle').each(function () {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#C0C0C0');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhb9A/87/